# How can I get to TTY from a broken login screen?

Tags: boot, 18.04, gdm, tty

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I just installed kernels 4.13.4 and 4.17.11 with ukuu to attempt to fix an overheating issue. This seemed to break all of my boot images as none of them will boot properly. Trying to boot an image myself through the grub console drops me into initramfs rescue for all of them. Using the grub boot options for any linux kernel I have installed brings me to a broken GDM login screen. If I enter my password it flashes a black screen before kicking me back to login. I am unable to open any virtual console either with Ctrl-Alt-F(1-7). The only thing I can do is reboot. Does anyone have suggestions short of reinstalling ubuntu?

EDIT
Was able to force the system into tty2 by spamming ESC while attempting to login and then Ctrl-C to cancel running GDM. Now I gotta find out how to repair my kernels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears installing KDE through the virtual console and then using `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and changing the display manager to sddm and rebooting starts the system in KDE, which I can still login to.